Salesforce pipeline failing for Ant build
While trying to build a salesforce sfdx program in Azure DevOps, getting below error using Ant task. Specifically shows deployment size is exceeding 5 MB which is new and unique error I am facing.
Starting: Ant build
==============================================================================
Task         : Ant
Description  : Build with Apache Ant
Version      : 1.246.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/ant
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\apache-ant-1.10.12\bin\ant.bat -version"
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.12 compiled on October 13 2021
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\apache-ant-1.10.12\bin\ant.bat -buildfile C:\agents\_work\21\s\build\build.xml "-Dsf.username=mysalesdeployment@test.com.giu" "-Dsf.password=***" "-Dsf.serverurl=test.salesforce.com" -verbose"
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.12 compiled on October 13 2021
Buildfile: C:\agents\_work\21\s\build\build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.8 in: C:\Program Files\BellSoft\LibericaJDK-8\jre
Detected OS: Windows Server 2019
parsing buildfile C:\agents\_work\21\s\build\build.xml with URI = file:/C:/agents/_work/21/s/build/build.xml
Project base dir set to: C:\agents\_work\21\s\build
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/apache-ant-1.10.12/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/apache-ant-1.10.12/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading C:\agents\_work\21\s\build\build.properties
 [property] Loading Environment env.
Property "salesforce.username" has not been set
Override ignored for property "sf.username"
Property "salesforce.password" has not been set
Override ignored for property "sf.password"
Property "salesforce.serverurl" has not been set
Property "salesforce.testLevel" has not been set
Property "lib.dir" has not been set
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/agents/_work/21/s/build/ant-salesforce.jar!/com/salesforce/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/agents/_work/21/s/build/ant-salesforce.jar!/com/salesforce/antlib.xml from a zip file
Build sequence for target(s) `deployCode' is [deployCode]
Complete build sequence is [deployCode, deployCodeNoTestLevelSpecified, describeMetadata, undeployCode, info, deploy, quickDeploy, deployCodeFailingTest, retrieveCode, deployCodeCheckOnly, cancelDeploy, retrieve, listMetadata, deployZip, proxy, retrievePkg, retrieveUnpackaged, test, bulkRetrieve, , deployCodeRunLocalTests]

deployCode:
[antlib:com.salesforce] Could not load definitions from resource com/salesforce/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
C:\agents\_work\21\s\build\build.xml:104: Failed to submit request to https://test--giu.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/48.0/00DcW000000VRGF for user mysalesdeployment@test.com.giu.
Error: {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE_REQUEST - EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE_REQUEST: Maximum size of request reached. Maximum size of request is 52428800 bytes.
    at com.salesforce.ant.SFDCMDAPIAntTaskRunner.runTask(SFDCMDAPIAntTaskRunner.java:50)
    at com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:63)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1401)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1374)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1264)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:818)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101)
Caused by: com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException: EXCEEDED_MAX_SIZE_REQUEST: Maximum size of request reached. Maximum size of request is 52428800 bytes.
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.createException(SoapConnection.java:226)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:163)
    at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:108)
    at com.sforce.soap.metadata.MetadataConnection.deploy(MetadataConnection.java:404)
    at com.salesforce.ant.DeployTask.submitMessage(DeployTask.java:326)
    at com.salesforce.ant.SFDCMDAPIAntTaskRunner.runTask(SFDCMDAPIAntTaskRunner.java:29)
... 18 more

Total time: 1 minute 20 seconds
The process 'C:\apache-ant-1.10.12\bin\ant.bat' failed with exit code 1
No test result files matching C:\agents\_work\21\s\**\TEST-*.xml were found, so publishing JUnit test results is being skipped.
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\apache-ant-1.10.12\bin\ant.bat' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Ant build


The error shows the Maximum size is 50 MB. It should be a limitation from salesforce instead of Azure DevOps Ant task. Refer to this ticket:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108856/ant-deploy-error-maximum-size-of-request-reached
